# Conditional Foreign Key implementation in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, indexing, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I have a  requirement as mentioned below:

```
table1
------------------------
A    B     C    D   E    
------------------------
1    2     *    P    Q
1    2     A    Q    P
1    3     B    W    U
-----------------------
```

Column `A B C` are the `primary key` on `table1`

```
table2
------------------------
A    B     C    
------------------------
1    2     1   
1    2     2   
1    2     A    
------------------------
```

column `A B C` needs to be implemented as composite foreign key on table2 
for column `A B C` on table 1, the only exception is ,if column `C` in parent table (table 1) is `*`
then any value can appear in `column C` of child table (table2) provided `column A` and `column B` 
are same in both tables.

We are looking for an implementation with minimal trigger .Currently we are not able to create foreign key because of this weird requirement.

Please suggest any alternate approach and make my day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be addressed without need of any new structure.
 just by introducing a new_column (NEW_C) in child table (table2)
and using this column in foreign key contraint instead of 'column C'.
Steps are below:

1>`alter table2 add (new_c varchar2(1));`

2>`update table2 set new_c= c`;

3>Use newly introduced column NEW_C instead of `colum C` in FK

```
alter table table2
  add constraint
  fk_ref_table1 FOREIGN KEY (A,B,**NEW_C**)    
  references table1 (A,B,C);
```

4>Create a simple insert/update trigger on child table to maintain new column `NEW_C`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE maintain_new_c
 BEFORE
  INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON TABLE2 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
 FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_count pls_integer;
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(1) 
   INTO v_count
   FROM table1 t1    
  WHERE t1.c='*'
    AND t1.a= :NEW.a 
    AND t1.b= :NEW.b;

  IF v_count=0 THEN
    new_c := :NEW.c ;
  ELSE
    new_c := '*';
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR..........
END;
```

Alternative is to introduce a new virtual column (oracle 11g) on child table, 
Use deterministic pl/sql function to
derive this virtual coulmn and then create foreign key constraint 
using Virtual column.

But I will prefer trigger based approach as any udate/delete operation on parent table
will suffer because need to derive and check Virtual column each time.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is a problem with the model. Both tables seem to represent two different types of things, which is why an ordinary FK constraint won't work.

I think you should split both tables into two, e.g.:

```
table1_noC
------------------------
A    B     D   E    
------------------------
1    2     P    Q

table2_noC (with a FK to table1_noC)
------------------------
A    B     C    
------------------------
1    2     1   
1    2     2   
------------------------

table1_C
------------------------
A    B     C    D   E    
------------------------
1    2     A    Q    P
1    3     B    W    U
-----------------------

table2_C (with a FK to table1_C)
------------------------
A    B     C    
------------------------
1    2     A    
------------------------
```

You can then recreate your original design with a view that combines `table1_noC` + `table1_C` and another view that combines `table2_noC` + `table2_C`. If necessary you can even add "instead of" triggers to the views to translate DML on the views into the necessary DML on the underlying tables.

Comment: :Application logic is based on these 2  tables, and introducing '*'  for 'column C' is a new requirement so new design containing 4 tables can not be incorporated, A solution which does not impact  existing functionality is required:(

Comment: "We want to make a change to the model, but we don't want to change the schema"... good luck with that :)